# Google Webmaster sitemap issue with Tags and Header

Tags: php, xml, sitemap, google-search-console

I am trying to make a news sitemap and sitemap file opens fine but on google webmaster tools test it shows two errors:

1. Invalid XML Tag
2. Expected: Your Sitemap or Sitemap index file doesn't properly declare the namespace. Your Sitemap or Sitemap index file doesn't properly declare the namespace. Expected: http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml Found: http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9

Any help Thanks in advance

```
header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'.PHP_EOL; 

echo '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">' . PHP_EOL;

$base_url = "https://www.example.com";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sitegrab))
{
    echo '<url>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<loc>'.$base_url.'</loc>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<news:name>'.$row['Website'].'</news:name>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<news:link>'.$row['Link'].'</news:link>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<changefreq>daily</changefreq>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<priority>1</priority>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '</url>' . PHP_EOL;
}

echo '</urlset>' . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to properly escape the special characters while building XML as text. For example `&` has a high probability to be part of an URL and needs to be escaped as `&amp;` in an XML string.

An even better solution is to use an XML API like XMLWriter to create the XML. It will take care of the escaping.